# Trying to filter an array using checkboxes and useState, checkbox doesn't stay checked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, checkbox, filter

i have an array, called `reportsData`, then i need to filter it, generating some checkboxes with each of them having a label based on each name that comes from another array (emittersData), so basically i set it like this:

`const [searchUser, setSearchUser] = useState<string[]>([])`

```
const mappedAndFiltered = reportsData
  .filter((value: any) =>
    searchUser.length > 0 ? searchUser.includes(value.user.name) : true
  )
```

Then i render my checkboxes like this:

```
function EmittersCheckboxes () {
    const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = useState(
      new Array(emittersData.length).fill(false)
    )

    const handleOnChange = (position: any, label: any) => {
      const updatedCheckedState = checkedState.map((item, index) =>
        index === position ? !item : item
      )

      setSearchUser((prev) =>
        prev.some((item) => item === label)
        ? prev.filter((item) => item !== label)
        : [...prev, label]
      ) 
      setCheckedState(updatedCheckedState)
    };

    return (
      <div className="App">
        {emittersData.map((value: any, index: any) => {
          return (
            <li key={index}>
              <div className="toppings-list-item">
                <div className="left-section">
                  <input
                    className="h-4 w-4 focus:bg-indigo border-2 border-gray-300 rounded"
                    type="checkbox"
                    id={`custom-checkbox-${index}`}
                    name={value.Attributes[2].Value}
                    value={value.Attributes[2].Value}
                    checked={checkedState[index]}
                    onChange={() => handleOnChange(index, value.Attributes[2].Value)}
                    />
                  <label className="ml-3 font-medium text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-primary" htmlFor={`custom-checkbox-${index}`}>{value.Attributes[2].Value}</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </div> 
    )
  }
```

And on the react component i am rendering each checkbox, that is a `li`, like:

```
<ul><EmittersCheckboxes /></ul>
```

And i render the `mappedAndFiltered` on the end.

Then it is fine, when i click each generated checkbox, it filters the array setting the state in `setSearch` user and the array is filtered.

You can check it here: streamable. com /v6bpk6
See that the filter is working, the total number of items in the array is changing based on the checkbox selected (one or more).

But the thing is that each checkbox does not become 'checked', it remains blank (untoggled).

What am i doing wrong, why doesnt it check itself?

Comment: Is this the real code or are you using React component to render each item?

Comment: I just put the individual functions so it would be easy to read, cause the whole file is huge. in case you need to see it, check it here: pastebin.com/5akZa2X4
(there are a lot of things unused in the code, pls ignore them, focus on the things i said on post)

Comment: You've defined a new `EmittersCheckboxes` component inside your parent component... it will work, but kinda strange

Comment: I don't get it, can't understand what you are trying to say. And it is not working.. the checkboxes doesnt stay checked.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined your `EmittersCheckboxes` component inside another component. and every time that the parent component renders (by state change) your internal component is redefined, again and again causing it to lose it's internal state that React holds for you.

Here's a simplified example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function CheckboxeComponent() {
  const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <span>CheckboxeComponent</span>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={checkedState}
        onChange={() => setCheckedState((x) => !x)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);

  function InternalCheckboxeComponent() {
    const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = useState(false);

    return (
      <div>
        <span>InternalCheckboxeComponent</span>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={checkedState}
          onChange={() => setCheckedState((x) => !x)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <InternalCheckboxeComponent />
      <CheckboxeComponent />
      <button onClick={() => setCounter((c) => c + 1)}>{counter}</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

There's the `App` (parent component) with its own state (`counter`), with a button to change this state, clicking this button will increase the counter, causing a re-render of App. This re-render redefines a new Component named `InternalCheckboxeComponent` every render.

The `InternalCheckboxeComponent` also has an internal state (`checkedState`).

And there's an externally defined functional component named `CheckboxeComponent`, with this component React is able to hold its own state, because it's not redefined (It's the same function)

If you set the state of each to be "checked" and click the button, this will cause a re-render of `App`, this will redefine the `InternalCheckboxeComponent` function, causing React to lose its state. and the `CheckboxeComponent` state remains in React as it's the same function.

Comment: I understand this, and i appreciate the effort but that does't work for the purpose i showed on my question.

To have a simple counter like you did.. yes, it works. But i tried isolating my component outside of the default function like you did, and it works the same way (the filters work but the checkbox doesn`t keep checked).

Could you maybe try to help me fix my component?

Comment: And also, i need to mainipulate my emittersData in many functions. If i set the emittersData, setEmittersData outside of my default function i can't access it through many functions.

Comment: hold your emittersData on the parent component, and provide functions to manipulate it to the children components. don't provide the object itself, changing it manually in the child component will not trigger a state change